# In flask admin, add confirmation prompt when Save new record

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Our users have the usual CRUD actions in various flask pages.

For one scenario, the Create action can be an intensive process, with lots of domain logic performed, and on occasion, items have been created accidentally.

Our users would now like to add a simple "*Are you sure you want to create this Account?*" prompt when they click the "**Save**" button.  The next response would simply be **Yes** and **No** buttons.

It's not apparent how to add this - are we missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the Flask-Admin create template for the particular view and add a JavaScript confirmation to the form's `onSubmit` event. Adding the confirm to the submit event handles the three submit buttons; 'Save', 'Save and Add Another' and 'Save and Continue'.

For example:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    create_template = 'create_user.html'
    # ...
```

In the /templates/admin folder add html file 'create_user.html':

```
{% extends 'admin/model/create.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="{{ admin_static.url(filename='admin/js/helpers.js', v='1.0.0') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $('form:first').on('submit', function() {
                return faHelpers.safeConfirm('{{ _gettext('Are you sure you want to save this record?') }}');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Note there's a [bug in Flask-Admin 1.5.3](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1887), helpers.js is missing from the distribution and you will need to add the `safeConfirm` function.

```
{% extends 'admin/model/create.html' %}

{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>
        (function ($) {

            function safeConfirm(msg) {
                try {
                    var isconfirmed = confirm(msg);
                    if (isconfirmed == true) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $('form:first').on('submit', function () {    
                return safeConfirm('{{ _gettext('Are you sure you want to save this record?') }}');
            });

        })(jQuery);

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey @pjcunningham, thanks for this response.  I'm heading off on holiday, but will try this out when I get back to the office.